# Multiple ModRewrite - .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to have two mod rewrites. Let me explain.

- I need one rewrite which if no file exist or directory exist, redirect to a userpage. | *I've already done this.*
 - Next, I want to remove the extension off a **.php** file.

I already have the first done, I just can't figure out how I would do the second?

My code already:

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ users.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

*So what I need, I just need to remove the .php extension and keep the current rewrite working.*

Comment: I think you have to do nothing. Just don't include the php extension in the request, your rule is already redirecting everything that doesn't exist to `users.php`. If what you need is to map to a resource according to the parameters in the request, give some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your complete .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

## redirect to a userpage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ users.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad to know that it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .php extension:

```
RewriteEngine On
# turn on the mod_rewrite engine

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
# IF the request filename with .php extension is a file which exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
# AND the request is not for a directory
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
# redirect to the php script with the requested filename
```

Just point to:

http://www.mysite.com/index

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I was more clear. I need both, not just the removing the .php extension.

Comment: If you are willing to experiment with your .htaccess file prior to going public. A document I found useful is: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html   this should clear up any other issues

Comment: @Jordan Did the link provided solve anythin?

Comment: Sorry, no because I don't know how to do more of a if statement. It's hard to explain..